# How to create a dummy variable in R for dates that lie between a certain interval?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr, while-loop

I have some hospital data that looks like this:

| patient_id | treatment_1 | treatment_2 | date_dummy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2012-01-04 | 2012-03-27 | 0 |
| 3 | 2021-07-11 | 2012-10-20 | 0 |
| 3 | 2013-04-04 | 2013-06-22 | 0 |
| 12 | 2012-12-09 | 2013-11-09 | 0 |
| 18 | 2012-02-25 | 2012-03-26 | 0 |
| 25 | 2012-10-06 | 2013-12-29 | 1 |
| 25 | 2013-04-06 | 2013-07-07 | 0 |

I need to re-create the `date_dummy` variable that equals 1 if the patient was treated again between the two treatment dates, and 0 otherwise. Patient 25 is the best example of this.

If anyone knows a command to do this using the dplyr package in R that would awesome. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Wouldn't it be good, if the actual overlapping row i.e second row of patient 25 flagged as `treated again`? Just asking for my knowledge, thanks.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67288732/how-do-i-determine-in-r-if-a-date-interval-overlaps-another-date-interval-for-th/67289069#67289069, is this a homework question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building upon @Rex Parsons answer you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('treatment'), as.Date), 
         interval = interval(treatment_1, treatment_2)) %>%
  group_by(patient_id) %>%
  mutate(date_dummy = map_int(row_number(), 
                       ~as.integer(any(interval[-.x] %within% interval[.x])))) %>%
  ungroup

#  patient_id treatment_1 treatment_2 date_dummy interval                      
#       <int> <date>      <date>           <int> <Interval>                    
#1          3 2012-01-04  2012-03-27           0 2012-01-04 UTC--2012-03-27 UTC
#2          3 2012-07-11  2012-10-20           0 2012-07-11 UTC--2012-10-20 UTC
#3          3 2013-04-04  2013-06-22           0 2013-04-04 UTC--2013-06-22 UTC
#4         12 2012-12-09  2013-11-09           0 2012-12-09 UTC--2013-11-09 UTC
#5         18 2012-02-25  2012-03-26           0 2012-02-25 UTC--2012-03-26 UTC
#6         25 2012-10-06  2013-12-29           1 2012-10-06 UTC--2013-12-29 UTC
#7         25 2013-04-06  2013-07-07           0 2013-04-06 UTC--2013-07-07 UTC
```

You may want to remove `interval` column from the final output if you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

to check whether a date is within the range of two other dates, you can use:

```
library(lubridate)
x %within% interval(ymd(20161001), ymd(20170930))
```

This checks whether `x` is between October 1st 2016 and Sep 30th, 2017.

I'm not sure what your date for 'treated again' within the two treatment dates is called but something like this may work:

```
data %>%
    mutate(date_dummy = ifelse(treated_again_date %within% interval(treatment_1, treatment_2), 1, 0)
```

Comment: I think that's on the right track, but I don't have a "treated_again_variable". The dummy needs to be created by person_id and with only the two treatment variables. I'm basically looking for if the two intervals overlap.

Comment: Ahh I see. I think I misunderstood your question beforehand but I see what you mean now. Glad you found a solution!