# How do I determine in R if a date interval overlaps another date interval for the same individual in a data frame?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a dataset of hospital claims. Each row is a claim, and I have the following columns: patient id, start date, and end date. Patients can have multiple claims if they visited the hospital multiple times. I'm trying to calculate the total time the patient spent in the hospital based on all the claims in the dataset.

```
library(tibble)
df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~start_date, ~end_date,
  "100003186", "2011-06-18", "2011-08-09",
  "100003186", "2011-06-18", "2011-08-23",
  "100003186", "2011-12-14", "2011-12-16",
  "100003186", "2014-09-14", "2014-09-17",
  "100003186", "2014-09-10", "2014-09-18",
  "100003187", "2011-11-18", "2011-11-30",
  "100003187", "2011-11-18", "2011-11-23",
)
```

The problem is that some claims overlap in their dates. For example, for id=="100003186", the first claim is from date 2011-06-18 to 2011-08-09, but this time period is already contained in the second claim, from date 2011-06-18 to 2011-08-23.

How can I delete the rows where the time interval is contained within the interval of another claim for the same individual (id)?

This question offers a possible solution, but I'd like to implement it by id: [R: Determine if each date interval overlaps with all other date intervals in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283935/r-determine-if-each-date-interval-overlaps-with-all-other-date-intervals-in-a-d)

Comment: Edit: I do not want to delete all overlaps. I only want to delete the interval that is contained within another interval.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a dummy variable in R for dates that lie between a certain interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275362/how-to-create-a-dummy-variable-in-r-for-dates-that-lie-between-a-certain-interva)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%within%` and `group_by()`!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Int = interval(start_date, end_date), 
                within = map(seq_along(Int), function(x){
           y = setdiff(seq_along(Int), x)
           #The interval is within any other intervals (in the group)
           return(any(Int[x] %within% Int[y]))
           
         })
  ) %>% 
  #and now remove those that are within another
  filter(within == FALSE)
```

Check out the documentation on `lubridate`, it's full of neat little functions!

Comment: Hi @dyrland, thanks for the answer! However, when running it in the code above, I get the following error. Do you know why this si? Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `overlaps`. x error in evaluating the argument 'b' in selecting a method for function '%within%': object 'y' not found.

Comment: Edit: I also do not want to delete all overlaps. I only want to delete the interval that is contained within another interval.

Comment: Whoops! In clearing out code from the linked answer I cleared out the line that generated `y`. I have edited the code.

I added a filter at the end that drops rows with intervals that are completely within another interval. I suppose you could convert that interval to null if you wanted to...

Answer (score 0):

Sort by start date, then look for any that have an end date less than the previous one.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
      arrange(id, start_date) %>% 
      group_by(id) %>% 
      mutate(contained = end_date <= lag(end_date)) %>%
      filter(!contained | is.na(contained))
```

This is "weak containment" i.e. it may delete some that have the *same* start date and/or end date. If you don't want that, adjust the `within` calculation as appropriate. The `is.na` call in the last line ensures we don't delete first rows per ID.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an older question, here's a newer option using the IV package dedicated to working with intervals:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ivs)

df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~start_date, ~end_date,
  "100003186", "2011-06-18", "2011-08-09",
  "100003186", "2011-06-18", "2011-08-23",
  "100003186", "2011-12-14", "2011-12-16",
  "100003186", "2014-09-14", "2014-09-17",
  "100003186", "2014-09-10", "2014-09-18",
  "100003187", "2011-11-18", "2011-11-30",
  "100003187", "2011-11-18", "2011-11-23",
)

df |> 
  mutate(iv = iv(start_date, end_date)) |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  summarise(iv = iv_groups(iv), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   id                              iv
#>   <chr>                    <iv<chr>>
#> 1 100003186 [2011-06-18, 2011-08-23)
#> 2 100003186 [2011-12-14, 2011-12-16)
#> 3 100003186 [2014-09-10, 2014-09-18)
#> 4 100003187 [2011-11-18, 2011-11-30)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>